# how to write the newline character as a string to a file java

Tags: java

how can i write the newline character as a string to a file java.
For example i want to write the string to the file "hello\nworld"
as it is to a file.

Thank you,
Rana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println("hello\\nworld");
System.out.println("hello\nworld");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a side note, you should be using System.getProperty("line.separator") rather than \n since this character is not always the system's line separator.

Comment: Also available from System.lineSeparator()

Answer (score 0):

steven is right.

you can also retrieve a list of all properties by using following code:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```